# Symfony - How to log a user on one sub domain (not all) dynamically

Tags: symfony, authentication, subdomain

I have a site with multiple subdomains. I would like to log users that have certain rights to one of the sub domain only when he's already authenticated on the 'main' site. Let's say that my main domain is www.domain.com, i have sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, sub3.domain.com.
When a user is authenticated on domain.com, i would like to be able to redirect him to sub2.domain.com without asking him to re-authenticate. But it should not be authenticate to sub1.domain.com or sub3.domain.com.
I have read about setting the cookie_domain in the config.xml but in this case the user will be logged for all subdomains.
Is that possible ?
Thanks !

## Edit for more info

I'm working with Symfony 2.7 and i have tried both solution  in the security.yml : one main shared firewall and one per sub domain (See below).
But i have not configured the session cookie_domain in config.yml to '.domain.com' as i don't want to log the user in all the subdomains.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        host: %main_domain%
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        anonymous:    true
        context: main_context
    sub1:
        pattern: ^/
        host: %sub1_domain%
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        anonymous:    true
        context: main_context
    sub2:
        pattern: ^/
        host: %sub2_domain%
        ....
```

Comment: You should specify which Symfony version you are using and if you've a firewall configured for each domain/subdomain in your `security.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in multiple ways. Since you log in in your main domain, you need some way to specify which user has access to which sub domain. Using different roles seems like a reasonable approach for this. So, for example a user who has access to subdomain1 will also have a role like `ROLE_USER_SUB1`.

With this set up, you can modify your `security.yaml` and use the `access_control` settings to restrict access to certain roles based on the domain, using [additional matching options](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#matching-options)

```
security:
    access_control:
        ...
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER_SUB1, host: sub1\..* }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER_SUB2, host: sub2\..* }
```

You might have to tweak this to your needs and you also have to be careful to have the correct ordering of the routes, as the first matching rule will be used.

Another possible solution is to use a simple event listener that is triggered on each request at the `kernel.request` (be careful to check the priority, as you probably need to put your listener after the firewall listener) or `kernel.controller` event and then use the access decision manager or `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` to check whether the user is (a) logged in and (b) has the correct role set, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/securing_services.html

Comment: Thanks ! Is this solution authenticate the user on a sub domain for which is authorized by the roles in the security.yml, when loggin into the main domain ?

Comment: Basically, when your user signs up either on a sub domain or on the main domain, you have to assign them a role or you have to add the role later, when they should gain access to a sub domain. By assigning them a `ROLE_USER_SUB??` they should have access to that sub domain as long as you have the acccess control setup. When they don't have that role, the should not be able to gain access to that sub domain and see a 403 error instead. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this is just one way of solving this. A downside of this approach is having to assign these roles and it can be easily misconfigured, e.g. using a role hierarchy or by having a wrong order in the access_control-section.  There are probably other ways around this, e.g. a custom Security Voter, but without more insight into your setup it's hard to tell which works best. I think as a starting point this should work well and from there you can improve based on what you need and what problems you encounter.

Comment: Oh, I think I misread your question. You will only need 1 firewall main (without host settings), that works for all sub domains. This is necessary, because otherwise you will not have the same user between domains. Each firewall provides completely separate authentication/authorization.

Comment: Peharps my question was not really clear... My problem is more about authentication, i'm already handling the user access internally. So when a user has logged on domain.com, and has the rules for accessing sub2.domain.com, a link to sub2.domain.com is provided to the user (this is working already). But the user needs to re-authenticate for sub2.domain.com when clicking on the provided link. I can partially handle this using cookie_domain and trusted_host in the config.yml, but it will authenticate the user to all sub domains not sub2.domain.com only.

Comment: If you use multiple firewalls you will have to re-authenticate. What you might be able to do is, look for a cookie/header/etc. and then use a guard authenticator in the sub domain to read this data, and fetch the user and then automatically perform the authentication without requiring credentials. I'm not sure if this is already available in 2.7, but see: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/guard_authentication.html#the-guard-authenticator-methods

Comment: It seems to be a good solution indeed. But unfortunately not available with 2.7. I can by the way implement in 2.7 style (more to do) or move to 2.8. Thanks !